# Address lack of details in change requests?

Tags: software-industry, communication

In SW company I usually work on assigned features and don't have many interactions with colleagues. I'm only one who writes code for the product and there's some language barrier, so it was fine. However sometimes my manager or colleagues receive issues from customers and ask me to analyze.

Recently I've received number of requests in the following form `Please find log` with log attached and no additional information about the issue, observed versions, any hints of reproduction steps etc. Same time our customers report at least product version and I know it for sure.

What is best way to address this kind of issues and force complete descriptions sharing?

Note: it's known that additional basic info (at least versions) are available for the person who requested me to look into the issue.

So far I've just added my lead in the loop and requested additional info. First mail I've requested from original sender wasn't answered during work day.

Comment: In my experience, you can't 'force complete descriptions sharing'. You can only encourage it - by sending stakeholders guidelines about how tickets should be raised perhaps. And maybe explain to them that it'll speed up the problem solving processing significantly for them if they follow your guidelines.

Comment: Go to the person who runs your help desk and ask them (or have your manager ask them) to receive such complaints only when a prepopulated form was submitted with all necessary fields filled out. On those fields, you can force them to select product version, screen reference where problem encountered etc.

Comment: @MelBurslan actually as mentioned it's received from other developers from my team. So, it seems obvious that as developers they probably know that any piece of additional info is important.

Comment: Ask your manager how to handle these. We can't decide that for you. VTC company-specific.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks for advice, I know managers opinion, but more interested in the right and efficient way.

Comment: You handled it the way I would handle it.  I do not think you have a problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return to the author with "insufficient information, please state the problem, what the context was when it arose..." In our company we have what are known as "must gather" requirements, and the first response to a PMR which comes in without the complete set thereof -- including the basic problem description you need -- may be to bounce it back as incomplete unless we are lucky enough to be able to get what we need out if the fragment they did supply.

Mind reading is not one of the services we offer. If you want something done, tell us/show us what it is.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, seems addressing it on some 'process' level is the only right option here.

Answer (score 1):

Give everyone who would be reporting an issue a form to fill out or a template to complete before they email through. The issue here from the sounds of it is that you're not being specific enough.

**Provide information on exactly what you're after.**

Telling someone to describe the problem will not give you the information you're after. The reason for this is that I can describe a problem in a single sentence and I've fulfilled your requirements of describing the problem. Then when I get a response back from you saying I haven't described it, I'll think you aren't reading my emails because I've already described my issue to you, what more do you want?

For this reason you need to ask the user "What steps did you take before the problem occurred?" or "What were you doing immediately before the problem occurred?". This restricts the user in what they can answer and lets them know what information is meaningful to you. They're likely under the impression that you can gain everything you need from the program log and any information they give you isn't that helpful.

Never assume that the person you're receiving your log from knows exactly what you mean. As was mentioned in another answer, you don't offer mind reading as a service. However, I'm sure that the people sending you the logs don't offer mind reading either, it works both ways!

Narrow questions will provide you more meaningful information.